# Which convolution algorithm Keras uses?

Tags: keras, convolution

I coded a general convolution function in Python for CNNs. 
As it turned out the time taken for this function was almost 5x more than the Keras Conv2D takes.
So I was curious **if anyone knows why is there a speed difference** ?

(It took almost 10-15min for 1 epoch of MNIST Dataset for my convolution function. Whereas Keras does it in almost 3-4min)

Heres my Conv class :

```
class Convolutional2D(Layer):
    def __init__(self, kernel_size, feature_maps):
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.feature_maps = feature_maps
        self.b = np.zeros((feature_maps))#np.random.rand(feature_maps)

    def connect(self, to_layer):
        if len(to_layer.layer_shape) == 2:
            kernel_shape = [self.feature_maps, self.kernel_size, self.kernel_size]
            self.layer_shape = [self.feature_maps] + list(np.array(to_layer.layer_shape)-self.kernel_size+1)
        else:
            kernel_shape = [self.feature_maps, to_layer.layer_shape[0], self.kernel_size, self.kernel_size]
            self.layer_shape = [self.feature_maps] + list(np.array(to_layer.layer_shape[1:])-self.kernel_size+1)
        self.kernel = np.random.random(kernel_shape)
        super().init_adam_params(self.kernel, self.b)

    def convolve(self, x, k, mode='forward'):
        if mode == 'forward':
            ksize = k.shape[-1]
            if len(x.shape) == 3:
                out = np.zeros((x.shape[0], k.shape[0], x.shape[1]-k.shape[1]+1, x.shape[2]-k.shape[2]+1))
            else:
                out = np.zeros((x.shape[0], k.shape[0], x.shape[2]-k.shape[2]+1, x.shape[3]-k.shape[3]+1))
            for i in range(out.shape[2]):
                for j in range(out.shape[3]):
                    if len(x.shape) == 3:
                        window = x[:,i:i+ksize,j:j+ksize]
                        m = np.reshape(window, (window.shape[0], 1, window.shape[1], window.shape[2]))*k
                        m = np.sum(m, axis=(2,3))
                    else:
                        window = x[:,:,i:i+ksize,j:j+ksize]
                        m = np.reshape(window, (window.shape[0], 1, window.shape[1], window.shape[2], window.shape[3]))*k
                        m = np.sum(m, axis=(2,3,4))
                    out[:,:,i,j] = m
            return out

        elif mode == 'backward_i':
            if len(k.shape) == 3:
                out = np.zeros((x.shape[0], x.shape[2]+k.shape[1]-1, x.shape[3]+k.shape[2]-1))
                x = np.pad(x, ((0, 0), (0, 0), (k.shape[1]-1, k.shape[1]-1), (k.shape[2]-1, k.shape[2]-1)))
            else:
                out = np.zeros((x.shape[0], k.shape[1], x.shape[2]+k.shape[2]-1, x.shape[3]+k.shape[3]-1))
                x = np.pad(x, ((0, 0), (0, 0), (k.shape[2]-1, k.shape[2]-1), (k.shape[3]-1, k.shape[3]-1)))
                fk = np.transpose(k, axes=(1,0,2,3))
                x = np.reshape(x, (x.shape[0], 1, x.shape[1], x.shape[2], x.shape[3]))
            ksize = k.shape[-1]
            for i in range(out.shape[-2]):
                for j in range(out.shape[-1]):
                    if len(k.shape) == 3:
                        window = x[:,:,i:i+ksize,j:j+ksize]
                        m = window*k
                        m = np.sum(m, axis=(1,2,3))
                        out[:,i,j] = m
                    else:
                        window = x[:,:,:,i:i+ksize,j:j+ksize]
                        m = window*fk
                        m = np.sum(m, axis=(2,3,4))
                        out[:,:,i,j] = m
            return out

        elif mode == 'backward_k':
            if len(x.shape) == 3:
                out = np.zeros((k.shape[1], x.shape[1]-k.shape[2]+1, x.shape[2]-k.shape[3]+1))
            else:
                out = np.zeros((k.shape[1], x.shape[1], x.shape[2]-k.shape[2]+1, x.shape[3]-k.shape[3]+1))
                x = np.transpose(x, axes=(1,0,2,3))
                x = np.reshape(x, (x.shape[0], x.shape[1], x.shape[2], x.shape[3]))
            ksize = k.shape[-1]
            k = np.transpose(k, axes=(1,0,2,3))
            if len(x.shape) != 3:
                fk = np.reshape(k, (k.shape[0], 1, k.shape[1], k.shape[2], k.shape[3]))
            for i in range(out.shape[-2]):
                for j in range(out.shape[-1]):
                    if len(x.shape) == 3:
                        window = x[:,i:i+ksize,j:j+ksize]
                        m = window*k
                        m = np.sum(m, axis=(1,2,3))
                        out[:,i,j] = m
                    else:
                        window = x[:,:,i:i+ksize,j:j+ksize]
                        m = window*fk
                        m = np.sum(m, axis=(2,3,4))
                        out[:,:,i,j] = m
            return out


    def forward(self, x):
        return self.convolve(x, self.kernel)        

    def backward(self, x, loss_grad, params):
        if len(self.kernel.shape) == 3:
            flipped_kernel = np.flip(self.kernel, axis=(1,2))
            flipped_loss_grad = np.flip(loss_grad, axis=(1,2))
        else:
            flipped_kernel = np.flip(self.kernel, axis=(2,3))
            flipped_loss_grad = np.flip(loss_grad, axis=(2,3))
        i_grad = self.convolve(loss_grad, flipped_kernel, mode='backward_i')
        k_grad = self.convolve(x, flipped_loss_grad, mode='backward_k')

        self.vw = params['beta1']*self.vw + (1-params['beta1'])*k_grad
        self.sw = params['beta2']*self.sw + (1-params['beta2'])*(k_grad**2)

        self.kernel += params['lr']*self.vw/np.sqrt(self.sw+params['eps'])

        return i_grad


    def get_save_data(self):
        return {'type':'Convolutional2D', 'shape':np.array(self.layer_shape).tolist(), 'data':[self.kernel_size, self.feature_maps, self.kernel.tolist()]}

    def load_saved_data(data):
        obj = Convolutional2D(data['data'][0], data['data'][1])
        obj.layer_shape = data['shape']
        obj.kernel = np.array(data['data'][2])
        obj.init_adam_params(obj.kernel, obj.b)
        return obj
```

Comment: Could you please share the function?. Maybe you can read [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/layers/convolutional.py#L361) to find how different is your function from the one Keras is using.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @RishabhSahrawat Ya I did checked that.. It calls a convolution function from CNTK library which is in cpp.. so I was not able to trace to the function..
(https://github.com/microsoft/CNTK The src is here alright but travelling through CPP seems tough for me)

Comment: Knowing that this is in CPP, im also starting to think, that is simply the reason of it being faster, but still thats too much speed up, and again.. even numpy must have its base in CPP right ? :(

Answer (score 0):

Keras and Pytorch are much more efficient because they take advantage of vectorization and the fact that matrix multiplication is very well optimized. They basically convert the convolution into a matrix multiplication by flattening the filter and creating a new matrix whose column values are the values of each block. They also take advantage of how the data is stored in memory. You can find more information in this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-are-convolutions-actually-performed-under-the-hood-226523ce7fbf